# Material UI : Reference other properties of createMuiTheme inside theme.ts file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

When importing theme like this (in filename.style.ts) :

```
import theme from 'common/theme';
```

I can access the different properties, like for example

```
theme.breakpoints.down('md')
```

I am trying to reference the same property *inside* the theme.ts file, but ofcourse.. theme. is not valid here, so i'm trying to to find a way i can re-use / reference it.

As you see on MuiTable i'm trying to access **breakpoints** and **palette/primary**.

**theme.ts**

```
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
export const MuiPaperBackgroundColor = '#f7f8f6';

export default createMuiTheme({
spacing: 8,
breakpoints: {
  values: {
    xs: 0, sm: 600, md: 960, lg: 1280, xl: 1650,
  },
},
palette: {
  primary: {
    main: '#3f18aa',
    extraLight: 'rgb(193, 181, 227)',
    noDataColor: '#cccccc',
    cardBgColor: '#ECECEC',
    chartColors: [
      '#E77F42',
      '#F3C3A3',
    ],
  },
overrides: {
 MuiTable: {
  root: {
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      '& tr': {
        '& td:first-child, & th:first-child': {
          position: 'sticky',
          left: 0,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.header.main,
          color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
          zIndex: 2,
        },
      },
    },
  },
},

},
});
```

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532599/how-to-use-breakpoints-in-theme-definition-itself/56533016#56533016

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell :) This actually solved it for me!.. Googled pretty much around to find a solution, but didn't find anything..

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: Just upvote the other and then I'll mark this as a duplicate so it cross-references to it (I can't mark it as a duplicate of an answer that isn't accepted and doesn't have any upvotes).

Comment: Upvoted your comment.. Thanks :)

Comment: Please upvote the answer to the other question (comment upvotes have no effect). Though Ricky's approach is also good and allows for leveraging customized breakpoints.

Comment: Done.. since both of them basically solves it, i upvoted Ricky's and yours..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use breakpoints in Theme definition itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532599/how-to-use-breakpoints-in-theme-definition-itself)

Answer (score 5):

Build your theme out of the individual `material-ui` packages. Here's how I did it:

```
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import createBreakpoints from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints';

const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({ 
  // your settings
});

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints,
  overrides: {
    MuiTable: {
      root: {
        [breakpoints.down('md')]: {
          // style
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ricky's solution is nice in praxis but Material [warns against importing deeper than two levels](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-1) (@material-ui/core/styles/foo in this case) because that is considered private and not part of any public contract. I.e., it can change any release.

It might not work with Breakpoints, but colours or fontWeights and such can be easily shared as plain constants declared before. But I am also sceptical if it's a good idea to include responsiveness in this declaration in first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the props after the theme is declared.

```js
let theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      root: {
        transform: 'translateZ(0)'
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    MuiIconButton: {
      disableRipple: true
    }
  }
});

theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);

theme.overrides.MuiCssBaseline = {
  '@global': {
    '.testMe': {
      color: 'red'
    },
    '.container-std': {
      [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
        maxWidth: '1200px',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto'
      }
    },
    '.container-wide': {
      margin: theme.spacing(2, 2)
    }
  }
};
```