# Unable to get custom breakpoints in theme

Tags: material-ui

So I would like to get my custom breakpoint values from within the `createMuiTheme`. I've tried the following but it doesn't work, the breakpoint values are is still the default value.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import createBreakpoints from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints';

const breakpointValues = createBreakpoints({
    xs: 0,
    sm: 800,
    md: 960,
    lg: 1280,
    xl: 1920
});

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    breakpoints: {
        values: {
            breakpointValues
        }
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiPopover: {

            root: {
                [breakpointValues.down('xs')]: { // This value is still the default '600'

                    background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)",
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So I've managed to get the palette values from within the "createMuiTheme" following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532599/how-to-use-breakpoints-in-theme-definition-itself/56533016#56533016 but I'm still unable to get my new breakpoint values using the same solution.

Comment: I used the solution in the second answer and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58651358/material-ui-reference-other-properties-of-createmuitheme-inside-theme-ts-file) and tried the first answer as a solution but could make it work. The second answer however did.